# What are the maximum levels for the different ship types?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

For example, I know that only a level 50 Man of War has 75 cargo space. 
But what about the other ships?
What is the max level (displayed when you use the spyglass) to achieve the maximum stats in Kennway's Fleet for each ship type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below are the maximum levels for each of the capturable ship types. The easiest way of bulking up your fleet is with Frigates and Man O' Wars, but having 1 or 2 Schooners and Brigs is beneficial too (because of their speed).

Best way of farming Frigates and Man O' Wars is to get maximum wanted level and then fast travelling to different naval areas. When doing so, within a minute or less of leaving dock, you will encounter both a Frigate and Man O' War. Try engaging them separately as they can still deal a fair bit of damage even when your ship is fully upgraded.

**Schooner**
*Level 11 – South Caribbean*

- Fire Power: 15
- Speed: 70
- Cargo Capacity: 20
- HP: 27

**Brig**
*Level 25 – Chinchorro and Charlotte Zones*

- Fire Power: 25
- Speed: 60
- Cargo Capacity: 35
- HP: 50

**Frigate**
*Level 38 – Chinchorro Zones, At Maximum Wanted Level*

- Fire Power: 35
- Speed: 50
- Cargo Capacity: 50
- HP: 70

**Man O’ War**
*Level 60 – New Bone, At Maximum Wanted Level*

- Fire Power: 70
- Speed: 30
- Cargo Capacity: 90
- HP: 150

The rest of the ship types and levels can be seen in this **[article](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-4-black-flag/Kenway%27s_Fleet)**. I'm not 100% sure on the levels of Gun Boats, but as you cannot capture them and how brittle they are, I don't think it matters all that much.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Lyrical has answered, there is actually one more type of ships both of which cannot be captured. 
The Legendary ships: There are five of these ships. All of them are Lvl 75. They are located at the four corners of the overall map.